# How to speed up a complicated query in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

How to speed up the following query execution? it took 65s just to retrieve 37 records. Any solution guys? (I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.6 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), 64-bit)
This is the query:

```
select cc.claim_id, 
cc.claim_date, 
CONCAT(cc.user_id, ' | ', uu.user_name) as user_name,
CONCAT(f_get_channel_id_by_territory_id(cc.territory_id), ' | ', f_get_channel_name(f_get_channel_id_by_territory_id(cc.territory_id))) AS channel_name,
f_get_cluster(cc.user_id) AS cluster_id,
ff.frontliner_name 
from t_trx_card_claim cc join t_mtr_user uu on uu.user_id = cc.user_id
left join t_mtr_outlet_frontliner ff on f_get_territory_id(ff.outlet_id) = cc.territory_id
where f_get_cluster(cc.user_id) = '36'
```

And this is an explain analyze output ([see also on explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/z97)):

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..83503.84 rows=646 width=47) (actual time=2000.830..65689.982 rows=37 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (f_get_territory_id(ff.outlet_id) = cc.territory_id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..433.50 rows=7 width=35) (actual time=174.417..198.364 rows=37 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on t_trx_card_claim cc  (cost=0.00..375.53 rows=7 width=21) (actual time=174.407..197.932 rows=37 loops=1)
              Filter: (f_get_cluster(user_id) = 36)
        ->  Index Scan using ix_user_8 on t_mtr_user uu  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=37)
              Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (cc.user_id)::text)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1811.51 rows=42701 width=21) (actual time=0.006..30.225 rows=42701 loops=37)
        ->  Seq Scan on t_mtr_outlet_frontliner ff  (cost=0.00..1347.01 rows=42701 width=21) (actual time=0.003..27.457 rows=42701 loops=1)
Total runtime: 65690.524 ms
```

Comment: Could you post the explain analyze output for this query? Potential problem I see is the use of the function in the where clause because postgres won't be able to directly lookup the right value in the index.

Comment: -1 because you should provide some info about you setup: start with `explain analyze`, tables structure, ... The 'postgresql' tag here links to some good tips: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Guide_to_reporting_problems

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for advice on info to provide.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new in this postgresql stuff. I even never know about explain analyze until you mention it. I've added explain analyze. thanks

Comment: Most of the time is spend in the topmost Nested Loop Left Join as the number of rows involved is fairly low I would say the f_get_territory_id used in that join filter is the culprit. The f_get_cluster is in a part that only takes 197 ms so that one isn't a problem. Could you post the code for the f_get_territory_id function? Maybe it can be optimized.

Answer (score 3):

Significant problem can be in functions f_get_territory_id and f_get_cluster - using functions in WHERE and FROM (JOIN predicate) clause is not recommended strongly (with exception if you use functional indexes / so these functions must be immutable).